# How logging request from "Authentication Required" popup in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, basic-authentication

I try logging request from "Authentication Required" popup in Google Chrome (basic auth), but I don't see any request in my network activity when auth is failed (I checked `Preserve log`), and also I don't see any `Authorization` header in my requests in logs when auth is success.

[image]

I saw `chrome://net-internals/#events` tab, but nothing interesting I didn't find (it is https requests).

I want to see `Basic Auth` request (with `Authorization` header) using `Chrome` tools. 
How could I manage this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this url:

```
chrome://net-export
```

By this url you may write all you network actions in one `json` file. And in this `json` file you may find `Authorization` header.